# socket.io-stream Livestream MediaStream

Tags: javascript, socket.io, electron

I try to make a livestream trough socket.io. To achieve this goal I send the MediaStream trough the socket and try to set it as a MediaStream in the Client:
Server:

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
    audio: false,
    video: {
        mandatory: {
        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
        chromeMediaSourceId: remote.getGlobal('screen').window,
        minWidth: 0,
        maxWidth: 10000,
        minHeight: 0,
        maxHeight: 10000
        }
    }
}, gotStream, getUserMediaError);

var ss = require('socket.io-stream')

 function gotStream(stream) {
    console.log("Got Stream! Starting websocket...");
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    video.srcObject = stream
    io.on('connection', function(socket) {
        ss(socket).emit("stream", stream);
    });
 }
```

Client:

```
<body>
    <video id="video" style="position: fixed; width: 100%" id="photo" style="width: 100%" src=""></video>
</body>                                                         
<script src="js/socketio.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io-stream/0.9.1/socket.io-stream.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io('ws://192.168.2.110:3000');
    socket.on('img', function(e) {
        document.getElementById("photo").src = e;
    });
    ss(socket).on("stream", function(data) {
        document.getElementById("video").srcObject = URL.createObjectURL(data);
    });
</script>
```